# Wix Burn failed to install powershell

Tags: powershell, wix, burn

i'm trying to install Powershell from the burn. intially i was using `<PropertyGroupRef id="POWERSHELLVERSION" />` but found that it won't work.

then i tried this using the registry scan but seems that it also failed.

Here is the code for the registry scan.

Thank
`

```
<Property Id="POWERSHELLEXE">
  <RegistrySearch Id="POWERSHELLEXE"
                  Type="raw"
                  Root="HKLM"
                  Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell"
                  Name="Path" />
</Property>




<PackageGroup Id ="PowerShell">
  <ExePackage DisplayName="Windows PowerShell"
              Cache="yes"
              Compressed="yes"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              SourceFile="X86\WindowsXP-KB926139-v2-x86-ENU.exe"
              InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
              DetectCondition="POWERSHELLVERSION &lt;= 0"
              InstallCondition="(VersionNT=v5.1) AND (NOT POWERSHELLEXE) AND (NOT VersionNT64)"
              />
```

`

any help regarding this will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is your InstallCondition, if you are checking for WindowsXP machine then it should be:
VersionNT = 501 (instead of =v5.1).

[Wix Source](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/useful-extras)